# Top level JSON object with multiple matches returned for each match

Tags: json, jq

I have this kind of JSON file:

```json
[{
    "name": "model1",
    "reference": 0.1,
    "code": [{
        "name": "foo",
        "version": "a",
        "value": 0.2
    },{
        "name": "foo",
        "version": "b",
        "value": 0.2
    },{
        "name": "bar",
        "version": "a",
        "value": 0.15
    }]
},{
    "name": "model2",
    "reference": 0.12,
    "code": [{
        "name": "bar",
        "version": "a",
        "value": 0.09
    },{
        "name": "baz",
        "version": "a",
        "value": 0.15
    }]
}]
```

What I want is to get all the top level objects for a certain `code.name`, let’s say `foo`. So I wrote the following query:

```
.[] | select( .code[].name == "foo" )
```

The problem is that since there is two sub-objects with `foo` as name, the top level object is returned twice. I’d like to have it only once, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`any/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)).

```
.[] | select(.code | any(.name == "foo"))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wOg22IU6uh)</sup>